# Getting Latest Date with field count

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 Tables to Join

> Subscription having column `CustomerID`
>   Report Pull having columns `CustomerId and ReportDt`

I want to have result as columns

```
CustomerId   LastReportPullDt    ReportCount
```

Where

> `LastReportPullDt =` Latest Report Pulled Date
>   `ReportCount =` Report Count for Customer

My Condition is to check for customers who have a record created for today in `Report Pull` Table  and also that customer should have atleast another record present so that the report pulled today is 2nd time or nth time report has been pulled where n>1.

> Example Data
>   Table **Subscription**

**CustomerId**

```
C1
C2
C3
C4
```

**Report Pull Table** 
`CustomerId`        `ReportDt`

```
C1            19-Oct-2016
C1            01-Oct-2016
C1            17-Sep-2016
C2            18-Oct-2016
C2            01-Sep-2016
C3            19-Oct-2016
```

The query returns only C1 as record, latest date as 19th Oct and 3 as count.
This is because only C1 satisfies that report date is today, and count >1 for no. of reports.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I am not getting intended result so i deleted that one.  

@GordonLinoff - I have added more info.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  It is Database of Salesforce Marketing Cloud. SQL Queries mostly run fine on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will only return customers who **last ran the report today** and have run the report **more than once** in total:

```
SELECT C.Id,
       MAX(RP.PullDt) as LastReportPullDt, 
       COUNT(*) AS ReportCount
 FROM Customer C
 INNER JOIN ReportPull RP ON C.CustomerId = RP.CustomerId
 GROUP BY C.CustomerId
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- MORE THAN ONE ATTEMPT AT RUNNING THE REPORT
 AND MAX(RP.PullDt) >= dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,GETUTCDATE())) -- THE LAST ATTEMPT IS TODAY
```

Just for extra info, this part:

`dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,GETUTCDATE()))`

simply removes the time from the date/time returned from `GETUTCDATE()` so that you are comparing any reports run from the start of the today (i.e. midnight).

Comment: Hello, What if i want the count to be exactly 2. I mean.. i want to pull customers who have ran their 2nd report only today. not more than that.

I tried modifying it to Count(rp.CustomerId) = 2, but it still returns me customers having report count more than 2

Comment: @PankajGupta HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 will return only Customers who have only ever ran 2 reports.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from (
  select 
    customerid, 
    max(reportdt) as LastReportPullDt, 
    count(*) as ReportCount 
  from "Report Pull" 
  group by customerid
) where LastReportPullDt='2016-10-19' and ReportCount>1
```

Comment: What should be the conditions for Latest Date and Count ?

Answer (score 0):

```
; with temp as 
(
    select  s.CustomerId, ReportDt, Rank() over (partition by s.CustomerId order by ReportDt desc) r
    from    Subscription    s
    join    ReportPull  r   on s.CustomerId = r.CustomerId
)
    select  *
    from    temp
    where   r = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

If you don't need customer_name, you can avoid using join part.

```
select
    reports.customer_id
    , count(reports.*) as num_records
    , max(ReportDt)
    , customers.customer_name
from reports
    left join customers
        on reports.customer_id = customers.customer_id
group by 
    reports.customer_id, customers.customer_name
having 
    count(*) >= min_required_reports
```